# Load HTML into webview in Android?

Tags: android, webview

I am loading following html content into the webview. But im getting following error:

> Web page not available
>   text/html;utf8%3C!DOCTYPE%20HTML%20PUBLIC%20//W3C//
>   ........

and more

This is my html content

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC '-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 

Transitional//EN'><html><head><title>Personality ABC</title></head><body><table 

border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%"><tr><td 

align="center"><strong>[Red-Blue] Sachin</strong><br /><img 

src="r7y3b6.png" alt="[Red-Blue] 

Sachin" title="[Red-Blue] Sachin" /><br />Sachin</td><td align="center"><strong>

[Yellow-Red-Blue] Test1</strong><br /><img src="5y5b5.png" alt="[Yellow-Red-Blue] Test1" title="[Yellow-

Red-Blue] Test1" /><br />Test1</td></tr></table><br/><p><strong>Harmony:</strong></p>
<p><strong>Test1</strong> and <strong>Sachin</strong> experience lots of similarities 

together. Both personalities have strong red (dominant, authoritative and impatient) 

and blue (rational, reserved and analytic) sides and understand each other&rsquo;s 

nature; both being rational, thoughtful but dominant, authoritative and a strong 

leader at the same time. Both love to be in control and love to be superior and have a 

need for progress and a love for challenges.</p>
<p><strong>Conflict potential:</strong></p>
<p><strong>Test1</strong> has all 3 personalities in one and<strong> </strong>gets 

irritated easily. It is like a mood switch from one to the other and back again: 

yellow (friendly, kind) to red (dominant, need to lead) to blue (rational, thinking 

through, being objective). This irritates <strong>Sachin</strong> because he/she finds 

it frustrating when someone cannot make up their mind. <strong>Test1</strong> 

sometimes feels confused and expresses it with: &ldquo;I am confused!&rdquo; This is 

difficult for <strong>Sachin</strong> to deal with.</p></body></html>
```

I dont know what is problem?

Comment: how do you load it? code please

Comment: did you try remove the tag <!DOCTYPE ...?

Comment: @fazo i am using like this webView.loadData(str,"text/html", "utf-8");

Comment: 1)make sure you have anything in str 2)delete doctype as ahmad suggested 3)eventually try very simple <div>text</div> as str

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
WebView wv = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);

wv.loadDataWithBaseURL("notreal/", data_html, "text/html", "utf-8",null);
```

Comment: This works for sure. One comment though, the mime type should be "text/html", according to http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml

Answer (score 2):

I have this code to open an html.

```
WebView web = new WebView(this);
web.loadUrl("file:///sdcard/file.html");//The file:// is the protocol and it's nedded for internal files
```

Comment: hi , i think he can load the html data without saving a file in sdcard etc,