# Any way to stop WebView built in scrolling

Tags: android, webview, scroll

I am developing an application in which I've to use a webview. My question is **CAN WE STOP WEBVIEW's BUILT IN SCROLLING FUNCTIONALITY?**

I have tried this so for:

in onScrollChanged super.scroll(0,0);

But this wont help me. I'm looking for something like we can stop zooming using the webview settings...

Anyone having better Idea other then this would be great.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Finally I've found the answer myself..:P

we can stop or start scrolling and scaling of the page by doing some javascript stuff in the page. Here is the javascript code:

```
function stopScroll()
{
    document.ontouchmove = function(e){ e.preventDefault(); }
}

function startScroll()
{
    document.ontouchmove = function(e){ return true; }
}
```

Now you can call these functions using your android webview using following:

```
myWebView.loadUrl("javascript:stopScroll()");
```

By calling above function stopScroll from the HTML page will be called.
Cheers!!!

Comment: how can we add javascript or javascript code to android .. Kindly tell me some tutorials

Comment: Make a simple/normal html page having javascript in it. And call function as described above.

Comment: where you add it in assets or somewhere else and what is the name of the html javascript.htm  I can't find where you refer the HTML document. Kindly share some tutorial on it..

Comment: Yes you can add HTML page in assets, or may be you can develop HTML String and load it into the webview. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5552578/load-html-into-webview-in-android

Answer (score 2):

```
WebView WebView1 = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);

//Only hide the scrollbar, not disables the scrolling:
WebView1.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
WebView1.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);

//Only disabled the horizontal scrolling:
WebView1.getSettings().setLayoutAlgorithm(LayoutAlgorithm.SINGLE_COLUMN);

//To disabled the horizontal and vertical scrolling:
webview.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        return (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE);
    }
});
```

// [details here](http://sharecoding.wordpress.com/2012/02/16/programmatically-disable-scroll-function-on-android-webview/)

Answer (score 1):

I can suggest to look at the problem from another point of view. This helped me when I had the similar issue. I found out that html meta tag "viewport" has great impact on WebView, especially if incorrectly specified. If the web page is developed and maintained by you, then  you may use the following meta tag to the  of your web pages:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; user-scalable=0;"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for response..

Also can you please tell me how to stop or START scrolling again???

Comment: with help of viewport tag you may set user-scalable=1. it will enable zooming so the scrolls will work if user zoom in the webpage. Web page causes scroll so it's essential to build a correct webpage more than trying to adjust the webview. I would concentrate on web design if it's your website.

Comment: it is nice but yet I only found how to stop scaling not scrolling...:S

Comment: could you make a screenshot(s) of what do you currently have with you webview. it may give a better idea what you are trying to achieve.