# Android WebView wrap text to newline and prevent horizontal scrolling

Tags: android, android-layout, android-webview

I am using a WebView to display content, however, content that is long creates horizontal scrolling, which is not desired. When I attempt to use methods like `setLoadWithOverviewMode()` and `setUseWideViewPort()`, etc, as all of the other solutions suggest, the text is shrunk too small to read. The Autosizing Layout Algorithm produces the same result as well. 
The desired outcome is to have the html retain its scale, but wrap the text to make it fit the screen, rather than scaling the text size down. Here is my xml, if its any help:

```html
<ScrollView>
        ...

        <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/details_fragment_description_container"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_extra_extra_large"
                android:background="@color/white"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/padding_extra_extra_large"
                android:visibility="visible">

            <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:paddingEnd="@dimen/padding_extra_extra_large"
                    android:paddingStart="@dimen/padding_extra_extra_large"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_drafts_24_biscay"/>

            <WebView
                    android:id="@+id/details_fragment_description_webview"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score -1):

Create an instance of your `WebView` within your **activity/class**, then call `setOnTouchListener` interface on your instance and disable the scrolling programmatically:

```
webview.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
  return (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE);
}
});
```

Then, within your **xml**, wrap your `WebView` with `ScrollView` and set `android:scrollbars="vertical"`

```
<ScrollView
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:scrollbars="vertical">
   <WebView
   android:id="@+id/details_fragment_description_webview"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</ScrollView>
```

Credit goes to [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11064104/5544859)

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work either. This solution merely cuts of the part of the view that does not fit on the device screen by preventing horizontal scrolling.
This is only part of the solution, as I would like the text that is being cut off to wrap to a new line, or to fit on the device screen _without_ scaling down in size.

Comment: I believe that this will have to be achieve from the website itself because what you are asking for is to not change the size and to not cut off the lines that goes beyond the device screen. Android xml layout will provide you with the ability to scale the size of the text so that it fits its screen or to cut it off, however I believe that it's impossible to create a new text line in the website itself from the Android API.

Comment: I am not displaying a website, I am displaying HTML text.

Comment: An alternative is to directly use your html text into your android but then you will get rid off WebView but that does not answer your question.