# How to stop INTERNAL scrolling of WebView in Android?

Tags: android, html, css, webview, scroll

I have a WebView in my application which has HTML content rendered in it and size of HTML content is larger than size of WebView. Due to which content is scrolling inside it when user drags his/her finger on it. I want to stop this INTERNAL scrolling being happening with content.

Heres what I have already tried so far:

```
WebView view = new WebView(context);  //context is of Activity
view.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
view.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
view.setScrollContainer(false);
```

and in CSS as:

```
overflow : hidden !important;
```

Kindly suggest solutions except **Disabling Finger Drag** (Hack) for webview because that disturb my other functionality, which is as follows:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
    if(motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE)
    {
        return true;
    }
  }
```

Comment: click [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5274400/4419437)

i hope this will help you :)

Comment: @asimmahmoodKhan I have mentioned all these solutions in my question. Kindly check first. Thanks :)

Comment: [click here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8654192/4419437) i think it this code will help you.Sory For Last Comment :)

Comment: @asimmahmoodKhan Thank you very much for your efforts bro.**+1** for your help. I have looked in your suggestion deeply. Actually this too is same as **Disabling Finger Drag**(Hack) as i mentioned above. This JS code is same as following Android code:
`public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
    if(motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE)
    {
        return true;
    }
  }`
It also stops scaling, zooming etc. Which is not what i have to do. Please look if anything else figured out. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a container to your webview that wraps all your content and sits just below the `body` element, like so:

```
<body id="myBody">
  <div class="container">
    <!-- All your content goes in this new div.container -->
  </div>
</body>
```

Then, add this CSS to your page:

```
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  pointer-events: none;
}
div.container {
  overflow: hidden!important;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

The problem is that a WebView seems to ignore scrolling on the `body` despite overflow rules, and since a `body` expands to meet its contents, it'll always think there is more to scroll to.  What this is doing is resetting the body to the size of the WebView, and then using the container to keep the body from expanding beyond the WebView with more content.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Yeah @Josh Burgess, that surely works!!! Me too did same thing at last when didn't found anything in android(JAVA). Just forgot to post here. Thanks a ton dude :) :) :)

Comment: Hy, I have tried your solution and indeed the scroll stops using the following command: overflow: hidden!important; but the problem is that my html is a flowable text, and I make horizontal paging so the user can flip the pages horizontally. This command clips the file so the rest of the html is clipped, I wish if I can stop only the vertical scroll.

Comment: It still clips the HTML horizontally

Comment: You have to disable all overflow hidden rules on the parent and the element itself, then only apply `overflow-y: hidden`

Comment: I don't have any overflow rules. if I remove this command: overflow-y: hidden. The flow goes back to normal, but I add it, it clips the HTML and disallow horizontal and vertical drag. I don't mind disallowing horizontal and vertical drag, but I can't have the rest of HTML clipped

Comment: I suggest you create a new question with a minimally reproducible case, then.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46845536/disable-web-view-vertical-drag-without-clipping-the-content