# Android Dynamic Html Data and Images Not display in webview?

Tags: android, html, image, webview

For my android app I want to load a html file to webview like this

```
webview.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/", text ,mimeType, encoding, " ");
```

I am use this Data display webview nice but My Images not display in webview.

`Question :` Why my html images not display in webview?

This is screen shoot for webview Image not display Any one Have Idea tell me how to solve this.

[image]

`EDIT:` Here my Html data is Dynamic not static.And my images also not come in compile time come runtime only.

Comment: Are you loading images from the web...? if so than you can directly give image url to img src

Comment: something like this String html = "<h1>Header</h1><p>Custom HTML</p><p><img src=\\"file:///android_asset/image1.jpg\\" /></p>";
    
    WebView wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.wv1);
    wv.loadDataWithBaseURL("fake://not/needed", html, mimeType, encoding, "");

Comment: my all html data load in webview `webview.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/", text ,mimeType, encoding, " ");` here `text` is html String

Comment: Than don't specify MIME type directly use loadUrl

Comment: than how to use that one...

Comment: as Ganesh Kumar said.....

Answer (score 1):

Try this code,it will work on all API levels..

webview.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/myfile.html");

Comment: My html file is not static every search change my data.

Comment: how to store my data in specific file every time

Comment: you have to erase the data in the file and replace the data

Comment: iam asking how to html data store in that file in first time

Comment: Try this.. webview.loadDataWithBaseURL("notreal/", data_html, "text/htm", "utf-8",null);ref:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5552578/load-html-into-webview-in-android

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24804/discussion-between-nagarjunareddy-p-and-ganesh-kumar)

Comment: this `webview.loadDataWithBaseURL("notreal/", data_html, "text/htm", "utf-8",null);` is also not working

Comment: chat not possible to my account

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem because filenames are case sensitive.

So if you have `image.PNG` saved, make sure your html file references `image.PNG` rather than `image.png`.