# Android webview cant load html text

Tags: android, webview

I am trying below code for webview, but i cannot get o/p in webview with given data input.

Below input text i want to view in webview.

```
String aboutUsString="
<p><img alt="" src="//c2.staticflickr.com/6/5783/20923557613_322bef1d7a_k.jpg" /></p>
<p><img alt="" src="//c2.staticflickr.com/6/5702/20923558493_cd3ff898b7_k.jpg" /></p>
<p><img alt="" src="//c1.staticflickr.com/1/688/21356640050_39abf858ba_k.jpg" /></p>
";
```

Webview code:-

```
 public void setWebpage() {
    if (!aboutUsString.equals("")) {
        webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webview.loadDataWithBaseURL("", aboutUsString, "text/html", "utf-8", "");
    }
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5552578/load-html-into-webview-in-android

Comment: Any reason youre using loadDataWithBaseURL("", aboutUsString, "text/html", "utf-8", "") vs loadData(aboutUsString, "text/html", "utf-8")? It's likely the problem is the formatting of the input string (things not being escaped correctly, etc)

Comment: I guess its your link problem

Comment: i already tried _loadData_ , but its cant work

Comment: @pRaNaY you don´t need to replace the html content, define de baseUrl : webview.loadDataWithBaseURL("http://c2.staticflickr.com", aboutUsString, "text/html", "utf-8", "");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try by adding the protocol(http:) to the URL you are giving to the 'p' tag.
Replace the `<p><img alt="" src="//c2.staticflickr.com/6/5783/20923557613_322bef1d7a_k.jpg" /></p>` 
with

```
<p><img alt='' src='http://c2.staticflickr.com/6/5783/20923557613_322bef1d7a_k.jpg' /></p>
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

if you have relative urls into your html content:

```
String aboutUsString="
<p><img alt="" src="//c2.staticflickr.com/6/5783/20923557613_322bef1d7a_k.jpg" /></p>
<p><img alt="" src="//c2.staticflickr.com/6/5702/20923558493_cd3ff898b7_k.jpg" /></p>
<p><img alt="" src="//c1.staticflickr.com/1/688/21356640050_39abf858ba_k.jpg" /></p>
";
```

You don´t need to replace the content, you must define the `baseUrl` to your method [**loadDataWithBaseURL()**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#loadDataWithBaseURL(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String))

> **baseUrl**: the URL to use as the page's base URL. If null
>   defaults to 'about:blank'.

This is the corrrect way :

```
webview.loadDataWithBaseURL("http://c2.staticflickr.com", aboutUsString, "text/html", "utf-8", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks @prasad. Problem solved by added below line in my code.

`webViewInput = webViewInput.replaceAll("//", "http://");`

Answer (score 0):

Try this piece of code:

```
    enWebSettings settings = content_wv_si.getSettings();
    settings.setDefaultTextEncodingName("utf-8");
    settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    wv.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, html, "text/html", "utf-8",null);
```