# How to force a WebView to load pages as html?

Tags: android, webview, mime-types

My app loads local HTML files in a webview. These pages load fine, yet, these pages have links to other local (w3c-valid, with all the headers) html files that do not necessary end in `.html`. In "normal" browsers, these pages are loaded as html (as I want). Yet, the webview loads them as text: it does not infer the mimetype, nor it assumes html by default.

How can I force the webview to load the linked files as html? Or, even better, how can I tell the webview to try to infer the mimetype?

BTW, my app has permissions to manage all files.

Comment: "My app loads HTML files in a webview" -- how are you doing that? "these pages have links to other html files that do not necessary end in .html." -- where are those files, and how is `WebView` loading them in? "Yet, the webview loads them as text: it does not infer the mimetype, nor it assumes html by default" -- do the HTML pages have a `<!DOCTYPE>` tag or anything that declares that they are actually HTML?

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more clear. The files are all local in the device. The initial html file is loaded with `webview.loadUrl("file:///....html");`, while the others load by clicking the links inside the original html. Yes, headers are fine: all the pages are w3c-validated as html, even if they don't end with .html. I edited the question.

Comment: Thank you for qualifying `webview.loadUrl("file:///....);`: that helps.  Q: do the HTML pages have a `<!DOCTYPE html>` tag or anything that declares that they are actually HTML?  Q: Does [loadDataWithBaseURL()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView) work?  See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6141569/421195

Comment: Yes, headers are fine. All valid W3C. Where's an example: https://luis.impa.br/photo/birdindexframes/ferro-velho, which gives no errors in validator.w3.org (after you add a .html to it, see: https://validator.w3.org/nu/?doc=https%3A%2F%2Fluis.impa.br%2Fphoto%2Fbirdindexframes%2Fferro-velho.html). The hack in my solution below seems to work fine.

Answer (score -1):

This is not a true solution, but a hack.
I override the `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` of the `WebViewClient` checking if the file has a suffix. If it doesn't, I load it as data forcing the mimeType:

```
myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    // Prevents exposing the URI in API>26 !
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        if (url.lastIndexOf("/") < url.lastIndexOf("."))
            return false;  
        else
            try {
                // Hack to load file without .html suffix as HTML
                view.loadDataWithBaseURL(url, readTextFileToString(url.replace("file://", "")), "text/html", "utf-8", "");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        return true;
    }
});
```

**EDIT:**

Instead of the `return false;` I first tried `view.loadUrl(url);`. This does not work properly when the page contains an `iframe` pointing to a local file, i.e., without `http...`: the iframe replaces the page, becoming fullscreen. Returning false here solved the issue.